# Proper way to call nested Expand() from .NET OData 4 Client

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services, asp.net-web-api, astoria, wcf-data-services-client

### Problem

In an OData 4 service on Web API, what is the proper way to call nested $expand from a .NET client?  We are using the [OData Client Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937).  Back in the prior WCF Data Services with OData 3 service we could call `.Expand("Customers/Orders")`.  In Web API with OData 4 we can no longer do so and receive the following should you attempt `.Expand("Customers/Orders")`:

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Found a path traversing multiple navigation >properties. Please rephrase the query such that each expand path contains only type >segments and navigation properties.

### Workaround

We are able to work around this by calling expand like so: `.Expand("Customers($expand=Orders)")`.  In non-nested $expand scenarios, I like the lambda support like so `.Expand(d => d.Customers)`.  Is there a proper way in .NET OData 4 client to call nested expands without the unfortunate magic string of `.Expand("Customers($expand=Orders)")`? If not, is there a cleaner string pattern like "Customers/Orders" that would work?  Thanks.

Comment: In the OData v3 scenario, you can see this [MS recommendation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc811ad3-a1e2-46d7-b263-abceecb67c93/exapnding-with-loadproperty-with-nested-levels?forum=adodotnetdataservices).

Comment: Thanks for the workaround for the .NET OData 4 client: .Expand("Customers($expand=Orders)") In an url you can use it like this: ?$expand=Customers($expand=Orders) Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28492946/2908623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OData v4, it is not valid to expand multi levels, such as what you mentioned in the question: .Expand("Customers/Orders"). I dont think the client will support such API. Here is what in the ABNF http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt:

```
expand            = '$expand' EQ expandItem *( COMMA expandItem )
expandItem        = STAR [ ref / OPEN levels CLOSE ]
                  / expandPath
                    [ ref   [ OPEN expandRefOption   *( SEMI expandRefOption   ) CLOSE ]
                    / count [ OPEN expandCountOption *( SEMI expandCountOption ) CLOSE ]
                    /         OPEN expandOption      *( SEMI expandOption      ) CLOSE 
                    ]
expandPath        = [ qualifiedEntityTypeName "/" ] 
                    *( ( complexProperty / complexColProperty ) "/" [ qualifiedComplexTypeName "/" ] )
                    navigationProperty 
                    [ "/" qualifiedEntityTypeName ]
```

Comment: @Tan_Jinfu Thanks, this is good information.  But it begs the question, why then does '$expand=Customers($expand=Orders)' work in the MS implementation?

Comment: Also, there is a [MaxExpansionDepth property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.enablequeryattribute.maxexpansiondepth(v=vs.118).aspx) on System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute that states _Gets or sets the max expansion depth for the $expand query option. To disable the maximum expansion depth check, set this property to 0._

Comment: Because the $expand=Orders in $expand=Customers($expand=Orders) is called a query option, and a query option can be $filter or another $expand, and the ABNF is:expandOption      = expandRefOption
                  / select 
                  / expand
                  / levels

Comment: How come it is not valid while it is clearly documented here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398162

Comment: Nested $expand and $select is supported in the MS implementation of OData v4 on the server side, but the issue here is how to construct such a query using the proxy generated by the OData Client Generator...  The key is to use the Linq select function to select the specific fields we want into an anonymous type.

Comment: I have Downvote because this answers suggest that it is not possible to achieve what the OP ask.., but I was facing the exact same problem, and the work-around suggested by the OP works very well.

Answer (score 3):

The request that you want to send is:

```
GET http://host/service/Customers/Orders
```

right?

According to the OData protocol:

> To request related entities according to a particular relationship, the client issues a GET request to the source **entity**’s request URL, followed by a forward slash and the name of the navigation property representing the relationship.

So such request is not supported as the "Customers" before "/Orders" is the name of an entity set instead of a single entity. You can only write nested expanding like:

```
GET http://host/service/Customers(1)/Orders
```

Which corresponds to the following code snippets using OData V4 Code Generator:

```
var orders = context.Customers.ByKey(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "ID", 1 } }).Orders.Execute();
```

And you need to iterate through all the customers to get all their orders.

Comment: @Yi_Ding, It's awesome to get a response from you.  However, may you please re-read my question? It appears you've mistaken the topic. When I say expand, I mean expand as in $expand.

Answer (score 3):

A little extension for that :

```
        public static DataServiceQuery<TSource> Expand<TSource,TNavigation,TExpand>(this DataServiceQuery<TSource> dataServiceQuery, Expression<Func<TSource, DataServiceCollection<TNavigation>>> expression,  Expression<Func<TNavigation,TExpand>> navigation)
    {
        var expressionName = (expression.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression).Member.Name;
        var navigationName = (navigation.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression).Member.Name;


        return dataServiceQuery.Expand($"{expressionName}($expand={navigationName})");
    }
```

Now you have intellisense and type checking

Example :

db.Container.Expand(c=> c.Customers, customer => customer.Orders)

Comment: This is a great answer, but I'm scratching my head over how you actually call this function....

Comment: Figured it out, this specific function is for dealing with properties on an entity that return a +Collection+ of entities.

So to use it, you might do this

r = container.MyProducts.Expand(p => p.Categories, category => category.CategoryType)

Comment: Yes, it's for nested object (or collection) in collection property. You could also use it like : r = container.MyProducts.Expand(p => p.Customers, customer=> customer.Orders) (like the initial question)