# OData v4 stopped expanding beyond 3rd depth

Tags: odata, expand

My app was expanding up to 4 levels just fine as configured all along until about a week ago, and now even with a sample project expansion stops at 3rd level. Here is my OData GET method and corresponding object model relationship, and the webApiConfig.cs file showing the MaxExpansionDepth set to 4.

I couldn't find any help anywhere, so I'd appreciate your inputs on this strange sudden behavior.

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("RotationSets")]
public IQueryable<RotationSet> Get()
{
     var rotationSets = new List<RotationSet>()
     {
        new RotationSet()
        {
             Id = 1,
             Title = "RS 1",
             Flights = new List<Flight>()
             {
                 new Flight()
                 {
                     Id = 11,
                     StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                     EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
                     SpotRotations = new List<SpotRotation>()
                     {
                         new SpotRotation()
                         {
                             Id = 111,
                             Code = "123",
                             Spots = new List<Spot>()
                             {
                                 new Spot()
                                 {
                                     Id = 1111,
                                     StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                                     EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2),
                                     Title = "Spot 1"
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     };

    return rotationSets.AsQueryable();
}

public class RotationSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Flight> Flights { get; set; }

    public RotationSet()
    {
        Flights = new List<Flight>();
    }
}

public class Flight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SpotRotation> SpotRotations { get; set; }

    public Flight()
    {
        SpotRotations = new List<SpotRotation>();
    }
}

public class SpotRotation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Spot> Spots { get; set; }

    public SpotRotation()
    {
        Spots = new List<Spot>();
    }
}

public class Spot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

}


public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static HttpConfiguration Configure()
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

        // No XML here.
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();    // Must be first.

        config.EnableEnumPrefixFree(true);

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", GetEdmModel());

        //routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var maxDepth = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ODataMaxExpandDepth"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var maxNodeCount = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ODataMaxNodeCount"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        config.Filters.Add(new CacheControlAttribute());
        config.AddODataQueryFilter(new EnableQueryAttribute()
        {
            PageSize = 100, //int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ODataMaxPageSize"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            MaxNodeCount = 100,
            MaxExpansionDepth = 4,
            MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = 4,
            AllowedArithmeticOperators = AllowedArithmeticOperators.None,
            AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions,
            AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Count |
                                  AllowedQueryOptions.Expand |
                                  AllowedQueryOptions.Filter |
                                  AllowedQueryOptions.OrderBy |
                                  AllowedQueryOptions.Select |
                                  AllowedQueryOptions.Skip |
                                  AllowedQueryOptions.Top |
                                  AllowedQueryOptions.Format
        });

        return config;
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<RotationSet>("RotationSets");

        builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, no one has an answer to this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28492946/2908623

Answer (score 1):

I fix this issue adding the desired element to the EDM Model and not sure if this is a bug or not (OData) but I think that when we need to either auto expand or expanding more than 3 levels it won't let us do so unless we add those entities that are not showing (or better adding them all) as a part of your EDM Model config.
For example:

```
builder.EntitySet<Spot>("Spots");
```

Also I have notices that if you are using Automatic expand like I do, you will also need to do something like:

```
builder.EntitySet<RotationSet>("RotationSets").EntityType.Count().Select().Filter().OrderBy().Page().Expand(Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.SelectExpandType.Automatic, 0);//0 disable the max check
builder.EntitySet<SpotRotation>("SpotRotations").EntityType.Count().Select().Filter().OrderBy().Page().Expand(Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.SelectExpandType.Automatic, 0);//0 disable the max check
```

You can also decorate the controller with:

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 0)]
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Enable Query on your Controller Action to override the max depth ...

```
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 23)]
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("RotationSets")]
public IQueryable<RotationSet> Get() { ... }
```

Comment: I'm setting the MaxExpansionDepth in the WebApiConfig.cs as follows, and I even tried your suggestion but no change, where maxDepth is set to a crazy value.

config.AddODataQueryFilter(new EnableQueryAttribute()
            {
                PageSize = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ODataMaxPageSize"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                MaxNodeCount = maxNodeCount,
                MaxExpansionDepth = maxDepth,
                MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = maxDepth,
                AllowedArithmeticOperators = AllowedArithmeticOperators.None,

Comment: My workaround unfortunately for now is NOT to use OData, but use a regular API.

Comment: I don't think it works like that, if you are binding directly to EF entities you might get some odd behaviour with things like inheritance I found it best to avoid stuff like that and keep to simple DTO's

Comment: I don't have any inheritance, what do you mean by that?

Comment: when you add entities to your model that inherit from something ...
class Foo : Bar {  } <-- inherits Bar ... that relationship for me causes odd side effects on Odata so I tend to only expose simple DTO's

Comment: Sure, but I don't have any inherited classes.

Comment: You have to have an entity set in the model for the entire chain that you expand through, setting the depth won't work even if a type is known in the metadata if you haven't called builder.Addset<T>() for all types involved in your expansion chain

Comment: Hello, I am having the same problem.  I wonder if there is a simple solution.